# appending the items into the combo box

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I need to add the item in a combo box for a particular number of times.This is my code.

```
         for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
         othercompaniesli.innerHTML=  '<select onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"><option VALUE="http://www.google.com">'+fStr1[0]+'</option>  </select>';
     }
```

Here I want to add the fStr1 string 3 times.But it adds only one time.That is the for loop is working but only item value is not appending.Only last value is added in the combo box. Can anyone help me how to append the items into combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tmpStr = '<select onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    tmpStr+=  '<option VALUE="http://www.google.com">'+fStr1[0]+'</option>  ';
}

tmpStr = '</select>';

othercompaniesli.innerHTML = tmpStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

try `othercompaniesli.innerHTML +=`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using equal to `=`, it is re-assigning to the same element

Use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('#othercompaniesli').append('<select onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"><option VALUE="http://www.google.com">'+fStr1[0]+'</option>  </select>');
```

Note that your `select` and `option` elements are repeating, you need to change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var select= $('mySelect');
var opt = new Option("OptionTitle", "123");

select.selectedIndex = InsertNewOption(opt, select[0]);

function InsertNewOption(opt, element)
{
    var len = element.options.length;
    element.options[optsLen] = opt;

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Here `select` and `opt` are being passed in the wrong order to `InsertNewOption` also, the select is a jQuery object instead of an Element so would need to be passed as select[0] or select.get(0)

Answer (score 0):

Place select tag out of loop

```
var selectTag = '<select onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
 selectTag +=  '<option VALUE="http://www.google.com">'+fStr1[0]+'</option>';  
}
selectTag +="</select>"
othercompaniesli.innerHTML = selectTag;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the inside the loop you are ending your select tag , so every element will have it own select opening and closing tag. and you are just updating your innerHTML with the newer element thats why its getting the last element.

```
 var openingTag= '<select onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    openingTag+=  '<option VALUE="http://www.google.com">'+fStr1[0]+'</option>  ';
}

openingTag= '</select>';

othercompaniesli.innerHTML = openingTag;
```