# Append the variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I need to append the values of fStr1 to some variable.This is my code.

```
     var myCars=new Array();
   for(i=0;i<companyLength;i++)
   {
     var othercompanies=new Array();
     othercompanies=companyrealObj[i].innerHTML;
     var fStr=othercompanies.split(">");
     var hreflink=fStr[0].split("\"");
     var fStr1=fStr[1].split("<");


     obj['name'+companyLength] =fStr1[0] ;
     myCars.append(fStr1[0]);


   } 

   alert(myCars);
```

here let say the companyLength=2 then the loop will be executed for 2 times.fStr1[0] will contain two values.Let say Hello1 and Hello2. I am appending the fStr1 to the myCars.But the problem is when I print the myCars it contain Hello2 only.Can anyone help me how to append the values of fStr1[0] to myCars.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: WHy are you asking same thing , you already posted similar tiype of stuff on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477879/appending-the-items-into-the-combo-box/9478041#9478041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
myCars[]=fStr1[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is `.push()`
so your code to append to the array should be:

```
myCars.push(fStr1[0]);
```

Comment: Using the sam_13's answer will be faster because it doesn't have to call a function.